# windows phone 8 device connecting to web api issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have a windows phone 8 device which i have unlocked for development . i have successfully deployed the app to my windows phone 8 lumia 820, but i am unable to connect the app to the web api which is deployed on my machine . how can i do it?

basically i think that i will be needing the ip address of the device. how can i get it

```
   <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:30134:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:30134:169.254.80.80" />
            </bindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone and your machine are different os's so localhost wont work (that would point to the phone). You need to make sure you machine is making the web api publically available on your network and then call it with your pcs ip that the api is available on.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, if you want to get Ip adress from device, u can get through this code. Just run it and go step by step debug, and you will find IP.

```
        var hostnames = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
        foreach (var hn in hostnames)
        {
            if (hn.IPInformation != null)
            {
                string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
            }
        }
```